# Adding If statement in html tag inside response.write of vb

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

hi guys i'm having a hard time doing some coding.

I currently have this code:

```
Response.Write "<option value='" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "'>" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "</option>"
```

and what i want to do is to add the if statement inside the above code like the one below with the select attribute inside.

```
<OPTION value="<%=TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"")%>" <%IF t_Assetcode=TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"") THEN Response.Write "SELECTED" END IF%>>test</option>
```

upon doing this will result to the automatic selection of the dropdown option IF it is equal to the t_Assetcode provided in the page.

any help will be much appreciated. TIA! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason why this code has to be obfuscated?  You can do the following:

```
<%
    Dim dbAssetCode
    Dim sSelected

    dbAssetCode = TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"")
    If t_Assetcode = dbAssetCode Then
        sSelected = "SELECTED"
    Else
        sSelected = ""
    End If
%>
<OPTION value="<%=dbAssetCode %>" <%=sSelected %> >test</option>
```

It is easier to read, and it is also slightly more efficient ( TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"") is cached ).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want , use the IIf it will fix your problem :

```
<OPTION value="<%=TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"")%>" "<%=IIf t_Assetcode=TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"),"") , "SELECTED", "" %>">test</option>
```

Not sure for the " around it :S

EDIT :

Here with the correct syntax :

```
 Response.Write "<option value='" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "'" & IIf(t_Assetcode = TrimPlus(rsReqNo("Assetcode"), ""), " SELECTED", "") & ">" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "</option>"
```

Comment: .I think you misunderstood my question. anyways, thanks for trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Dim outputString
outputString = "<option value='" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "'"
If t_Assetcode = TrimPlus(rs("Assetcode"), "") Then
    outputString = outputString & " SELECTED"
End If
outputString = outputString & ">" & Trimplus(rs("User_Doc_No"),"") & "</option>"
Response.Write outputString
```

Comment: I haven't checked your syntax. I've just added conditional "SELECTED" case into your code. I will examine the syntax now.

Comment: I'm not sure weather to use rsReqNo or rs for Assetcode (since i'm not able to see rest of your code). Please make necessery changes.

Comment: .I have replaced those that are needed to be. but still no luck.

Comment: Is the code which you refered as "I currently have this code" works correctly except being able to select? Or it doesn't work, either?

Comment: .yes it is working. but without the select. by the way this code is placed on an ajax page.

Comment: so, you should have tagged this as ASP, not VB6, right? :) IIf doesn't work for ASP but you can still use it by adding a function which you can find at this link. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219271

Comment: .can't you substitute the Iif part into if then else? :)